# Django nose giving "ImportError: cannot import name setup"?

Tags: python, django, django-nose

Django-nose installed in virtualenv is giving "ImportError: cannot import name setup" in runner.py when I run default server. On doing traceback I get this:

```
File "/home/sid/.virtualenvs/workbench/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 222, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)

  File "/home/sid/.virtualenvs/workbench/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 250, in execute
    translation.activate('en-us')

  File "/home/sid/.virtualenvs/workbench/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 90, in activate
    return _trans.activate(language)

  File "/home/sid/.virtualenvs/workbench/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 183, in activate
    _active.value = translation(language)

  File "/home/sid/.virtualenvs/workbench/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 172, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)

  File "/home/sid/.virtualenvs/workbench/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 154, in _fetch
    app = import_module(appname)

  File "/home/sid/.virtualenvs/workbench/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)

  File "/home/sid/.virtualenvs/workbench/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_nose/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django_nose.runner import BasicNoseRunner, NoseTestSuiteRunner

  File "/home/sid/.virtualenvs/workbench/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_nose/runner.py", line 19, in <module>
    from django import setup
ImportError: cannot import name setup
`
```

I found this about [django.setup()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage) on django documentation, though most of problems like this have pythonic issues rather than with Django

Comment: If you simply write import django and then use django.setup() wherever required, as depicted in the official documentation, then is it not working for you?

Comment: What Django version are you using?

Comment: @knbk django version 1.5 and yes it is not working even though implementation is same as docs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django 1.5 hasn't been supported for quite a while now, and django-nose has dropped compatibility in their more recent versions. `django.setup()` was added in Django 1.7.

You need to upgrade Django or downgrade django-nose to a compatible version. I would recommend to upgrade Django to a [supported version](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/#supported-versions) so you'll receive bugfixes and security updates.

Answer (score 0):

Django-nose dropped support for Django 1.5 in [version 1.4.4](https://github.com/jazzband/django-nose/releases/tag/v1.4.4).

I was able to fix this by installing django-nose at 1.4.3.

```
pip install django-nose==1.4.3
```